# listings package changes hyphens to minus signs

Tags: listings, unicode, punctuation

The [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package transforms source-code hyphens (`-`, U+002D) into minus signs (`−`, U+2212) when using the default proportional fonts, though not when using the default monospaced typewriter font.  A minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=C}

\begin{document}
  \lstinline[basicstyle=\rmfamily]{--x} \textrm{-{}-x} \par
  \lstinline[basicstyle=\sffamily]{--x} \textsf{-{}-x} \par
  \lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily]{--x} \texttt{-{}-x}
\end{document}
```

The first two rendered lines clearly show the difference between the long minus signs and the short hyphens:

[image: long minus signs replacing short hyphens in Roman and sans serif listings, but not monospaced]

This is not just an aesthetic problem.  The listing is genuinely no longer correct code.  A minus sign is not a hyphen, and the syntax of C (and most other languages) does not treat them as interchangeable.  `--x` is valid C code, but `−−x` is not.  If a non-Unicode-savvy person tries to copy and paste the code from such a listing, she may find that it does not compile but be baffled as to the problem.

How can I prevent `listings` from turning hyphens into minus signs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `literate={-}{-}1` to lstset. E.g:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=C, literate={-}{-}1}

\begin{document}
  \lstinline[basicstyle=\rmfamily]{--x} \textrm{-{}-x} \par
  \lstinline[basicstyle=\sffamily]{--x} \textsf{-{}-x} \par
  \lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily]{--x} \texttt{-{}-x}
\end{document}
```

[image]

See [lstlisting manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf) section 6.4.

Comment: +1 It's nice to see how 7 years later a better solution to this problem has been given! I've deleted my old answer, as this one is much cleaner and doesn't have the unwanted side effects that mine did.

Comment: Simply set `literate={-}{-}1` may let `-` absorbs following spaces in flexible and fullflexible column mode, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/445691. I recommend the solution in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/424193, which redefines the processor of `-` to get rid of math mode minus sign.