# Avoiding "minus sign" dash in listings commentstyle

Tags: listings, punctuation

Is there a general way to get `listings` package to

- typeset a hyphen as a minus character in the rest of the code (the default behavior), but
- typeset a hyphen as a *true hyphen* if it occurs in comments (using roman typeface)?

Here is relatively minimal example demonstrating my concern.  Note the minus sign character in the second comment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=C, commentstyle=\rmfamily, columns=flexible}

\begin{document}
\noindent
$x = a - b$  // perform standard sanity-check
\begin{lstlisting}
x = a - b // perform listings sanity-check
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Techniques that do not seem to suffice:

1. using `literate` for replacements. As best I can tell, those affect both `basicstyle` and `commentstyle`, so they would not differentiate as desired.
2. using `escapechar` to render comment differently.  If at all possible, I would like a general solution that does not require any change to the original program source code (presuming use of `\lstinputlisting`).

**Revision** (in response to Marco's answer below).

It would be ideal if it could properly handle any form of legal comment without needing to edit source code, for example:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
x = a - b // perform $5 worth of listings sanity-check [ideally]
\end{lstlisting}
```

Note: my question is related to [past question about hyphens and minus sign](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33185/listings-package-changes-hyphens-to-minus-signs) however in my case, I like the use of the minus sign in the actual code, just not in the comment.

Comment: Check that other packages are not interfering, I resolved this issue by commenting out: `\usepackage{breqn}`

Answer (score 7):

You can use the option `texcl`. For more information have look to the documentation.

**EDIT**

Based on the edit of Michael -- A simple solution is to change the catcode of special characters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=C, commentstyle={\rmfamily\catcode`\$=11}, columns=flexible,texcl}

\begin{document}
\noindent
$x = a - b$  // perform standard sanity-check
\begin{lstlisting}
x = a - b // perform listings sanity-check
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}
x = a - b // perform $5 worth of listings sanity-check [ideally]
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT 2** (thanks to egreg)

Michael requests a solution without using `texcl`. AFAIK this isn't possible.
If you don't say `texcl`, the `-` is always interpreted as `$-$;` this has nothing to do with the `catcode` of -

One should change the interpretation of `-;` but, AFAIK, it's not possible to change it in comments and not in the code proper.

Comment: That is excellent solution for this simple example. Thanks. But I'd be in trouble if my native source code files contain any special tex characters (e.g., $[]{}/). For example, what if the comment in the source code had been "// perform $5 worth of sanity-check".  In the purest sense, this solution doesn't satisfy the goal of not requiring change to the native source code.

Comment: much thanks. So in that way, I won't need to edit source code, but will just need to alter commentstyle for those listings that I notice to have such a character.  Could such a catcode be used directly as solution for the original problem (without use of texcl).  That is, is there a pure solution without texcl by changing commentstyle with catcode to force '-' character to be hyphen rather than minus?

Comment: @Michael: Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As a followup for the archive, I have settled on the following solution that provides minus signs in the source code and hyphens in comments (but without use of `texcl`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\makeatletter
\lst@CCPutMacro\lst@ProcessOther {"2D}{\lst@ttfamily{-{}}{-{}}}
\@empty\z@\@empty
\makeatother
\lstset{language=C, commentstyle=\rmfamily, columns=flexible, literate=*{-}{$-$}1}

\begin{document}
\noindent
$x = a - b$  // perform \$5 of standard sanity-check
\begin{lstlisting}  
x = a - b // perform $5 of listings sanity-check [ideally]                                           
\end{lstlisting}                                                                             
\end{document}
```

This relies on a [technique suggested by Alan Munn (for a related question)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33185/listings-package-changes-hyphens-to-minus-signs#33188) to override the use of a minus-sign replacement throughout listings, and then the fact that `literate*` syntax will add the substitution back for the source code, but not comments/strings.

Answer (score 1):

The following approach doesn't require altering the listing or changing any catcode.

[image: output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset
{
    language     = C,
    commentstyle = \rmfamily,
    columns      = flexible,
    literate     = {-}{{\Processdash}}1,
    keepspaces,
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\Processdash%
{%
    \lst@ifLmode% if in one-line comment mode
        -%
    \else%
        $-$%
    \fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
$x = a - b$  // perform standard sanity-check

\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single]
x = a - b // perform listings sanity-check
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single]
x = a - b // perform $5 worth of listings sanity-check [ideally]
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```