# Copy-pastable code using listings

Tags: beamer, listings

I'd like to have code in a PDF that someone can simply copy, paste, and use. Currently, `\lstlisting` is converting '-' to em dashes. Then when I paste the output into the Python interpreter or MATLAB, I get syntax errors. None of the solutions I've looked at on here seem to work.

```
myvar = 9
myvar = myvar - 2
```

The '-' ends up as '−' in the output.

I have the following settings

```
\lstset{breakatwhitespace,
language=MATLAB,
columns=fullflexible,
keepspaces,
breaklines,
tabsize=3, 
showstringspaces=false,
extendedchars=true,
basicstyle=\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont\scriptsize,
keywordstyle=\color{orange},
upquote=true}
```

I am using `\documentclass{beamer}`

I've looked at

1. [listings package changes hyphens to minus signs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33185/listings-package-changes-hyphens-to-minus-signs?noredirect=1&lq=1)
2. less relevant since i'm focusing on code, not comments: [Avoiding "minus sign" dash in listings commentstyle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40415/avoiding-minus-sign-dash-in-listings-commentstyle)

Comment: May be related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30284/how-to-make-listings-code-correct-copyable-from-pdf-and-with-hyperlink

Comment: never tried, but maybe an alternative? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117792/listings-copy-to-clipboard-feature

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `literate` to change possible automated conversions. In this specific case, using `literate={-}{-}1` substitutes `-` for `-` as-is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{listings,textcomp}

\lstset{
  breakatwhitespace,
  language=MATLAB,
  columns=fullflexible,
  keepspaces,
  breaklines,
  tabsize=3, 
  showstringspaces=false,
  extendedchars=true,
  basicstyle=\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont\scriptsize,
  keywordstyle=\color{orange},
  upquote=true,
  literate={-}{-}1}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{A listing}

\begin{lstlisting}
myvar = 9
myvar = myvar - 2
\end{lstlisting}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is very nice and simple. I was fearful of the other solutions that used \makeatletter and so on, things I'm not too familiar with. The issue with having to respecify fonts seems to have fixed itself as well.