# How can I instruct listings package to correctly handle SQL comments in external source files?

Tags: listings, comments

The listings in SQL containing `--` style comments come across as `−−` when pasted from PDF (if `lmodern` is used, otherwise as `??`). I looked at these answers but do not see how I could use them with the listings (which I mostly load from the external files (if that matters): [How do I prevent LaTeX from creating en-dash and em-dash?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36692/how-do-i-prevent-latex-from-creating-en-dash-and-em-dash/36730#36730)

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{memoir}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstloadlanguages{SQL}

\lstset {
    frameround=fttt
    ,language=SQL
    ,numbers=left
    ,breaklines=true
    ,showstringspaces=false
    ,columns=flexible
    ,keepspaces=true
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
select 1
-- This is just a comment
select 2
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The results look as follows in Sql Studio after pasting from PDF (third line is what they should look like):

[image]

EDIT:

I tried using the method proposed in [listings package changes hyphens to minus signs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33185/listings-package-changes-hyphens-to-minus-signs) and it worked fine for just the common SQL comment lines (ex: `-- This is a comment`), but it had a side effect on the output listings, where the field names are separated from data with the lines containing multiple dashes:

```
field1
--------------
1.33333333
```

These have an extra space after the first 2 dashes and look as follows:

[image]

MWE with the linked suggestion implemented:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{memoir}
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\lst@CCPutMacro\lst@ProcessOther {"2D}{\lst@ttfamily{-{}}{-{}}}
\@empty\z@\@empty
\makeatother

\lstset {
    frameround=fttt
    ,language=SQL
    ,breaklines=true
    ,columns=flexible
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={extra spaces},label={lst:sp},nolol=true,numbers=none]
field1
--------------
1.3333333

field1    field2
--------- --------------
9.66667   9.66667
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How can that be used with the externally input listings?

Comment: It should work with either. It just overrides the default substitution that `listings` does for the hypen.

Comment: That's right, it does!

Comment: Just put the lines of code starting at `\makeatletter` and ending with `\makeatother` into your preamble after loading `listings`.  That's all you need to do.

Comment: Yes, that did it!

Comment: @AlanMunn Updated the question and commented on the linked question that this does not work for the lines consisting entirely of multiple dashes.

Comment: Can you update your example code with the extra code from the linked question the new problem code and then we can reopen the question.

Comment: @AlanMunn Done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of problem with the uneven spacing is the `columns=flexible` option: with it listings tries to reinsert missing space after each "block" of input, in your case after two `--` as they consist of a block due to the comment definition. As the hyphen is a bit smaller then the default column width of 0.45em, you get an space.

There are various ways to get around the problem:

Make the default width of a flexible column smaller:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={extra spaces},label={lst:sp},nolol=true,numbers=none,%
                   basewidth={0.6em,0.37em}
                   ]
```

Make the hyphen larger:

```
\lst@CCPutMacro\lst@ProcessOther {"2D}{\lst@ttfamily{-{}}{{\Large-}{}}}
\@empty\z@\@empty
```

or put it in a larger box:

```
\lst@CCPutMacro\lst@ProcessOther {"2D}{\lst@ttfamily{-{}}{\makebox[0.45em]{-}{}}}
\@empty\z@\@empty
```

Comment: Added `basewidth` from the 1st option to `lstset` and it worked.