# Having problems with lstlistings displaying minus symbol in code listing with custom font

Tags: fonts, listings, texlive

I'm just trying to insert source code into the LaTeX file with `listings` package.
the TeX code goes as follows:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\Monaco{Monaco}
\lstset{ 
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\Monaco
}

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[language=C++]{filename.cpp}
\end{document}
```

However, the `-` symbol in the code was not displayed in the font `Monaco` I used, instead, it's using the Math-Type minus. (As shown in the image below)
[image: Display]

I searched it on google and found several fixes, e.g. `column=texcl`, but none of them worked.
Thank you for your help in advance.

btw, The environment is TeXLive 2017 on Windows 10

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please don't post such fragments of code only. Provide a minimal compilable document that has this issue

Comment: edited accordingly

Comment: A better solution can be found at [unicode - listings package changes hyphens to minus signs - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33185/listings-package-changes-hyphens-to-minus-signs)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can change the definition like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\Arial{Arial}
\lstset{
basicstyle=\footnotesize\Arial
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
a-b
\end{lstlisting}
\makeatletter
\lst@CCPutMacro
    \lst@ProcessOther {"2D}{\lst@ttfamily{-{}}{-}}
    \@empty\z@\@empty
\makeatother

\begin{lstlisting}
a-b
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]