# Broken dash output in listings (noto font)

Tags: fonts, xetex, listings, font-encodings, noto

I'm trying to use the "noto-sans" font found in the LaTeX Font Catalog, unfortunately each dash (-) produces a tombstone (▯) as output.

Here is an MWE:

```
%!TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{noto-mono}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[
    language=C,
    basicstyle={\small\notomono}
]
int main() {
    printf("----");
    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Broken output]

Comment: change the definition of the hyphen https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/424193/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you very much, what is the cause of this behavior? Does it depend on some sort of font feature?

Comment: @testa_a_posto Putting in `\tracinglostchars=2` and using system fonts instead shows that Noto Sans Mono font does not have the minus sign (U+2212; `listings` package maps hyphen (U+002D) to minus sign for `\ttfamily`), so it comes out tofu; but Noto Mono font does have the minus sign. The `noto-mono` package explicitly supports Noto Sans Mono.