# How to copy minus as hyphen?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, pdf, copy-paste

There is [a question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33185/listings-package-changes-hyphens-to-minus-signs) about minuses in `listings`.

Is it possible to make (document-wide) the minus sign (`−`) to look like the typographic minus, but be copied from the resulting PDF as the hyphen (`-`), used in source code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\newcommand\pdfminus{\BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=-}-\EndAccSupp{}}
\begin{document}
$\pdfminus A \pdfminus B = C$

$-A - B = C$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Copy/paste yields:

```
-A - B = C
A  B = C
```

**SUPPLEMENT**

The OP comments on how it would be nice to have it done automatically.  Unfortunately, redefining `-` as an active character everywhere I can only assume will break all negative numerical/length arguments.  However, one could scope the `\active` nature of `-` to only apply it in places where it wouldn't break stuff:

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\svminus-
\usepackage{accsupp}
\newcommand\pdfminus{%
  \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=-}\svminus\EndAccSupp{}}
{\catcode`-=\active \gdef-{\pdfminus}}
\newcommand\pdfminusON{\catcode`-=\active }
\newcommand\pdfminusOFF{\catcode`-=12 }
\begin{document}
\pdfminusON$- A - B = C$ Special $-$\pdfminusOFF

\vspace{-1cm}$-A - B = C$ Normal $-$
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
-A - B = C Special -
A  B = C Normal
```

Comment: Is it possible to seamlessly substitute it, without creating a new command and typing it every time?

Comment: @homocomputeris There is no way, in a general sense, to do this in `pdflatex` (maybe there is in `lualatex`...I don't know).  What can be done is temporarily making `-` active and redirecting it to `\pdfminus` within the scope of the `\active` minus.  However, you can't leave it active all the time, or it screws up any calculation requiring a length or integer subtraction.

Comment: @homocomputeris Please see the **SUPPLEMENT** in my answer.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! If it cannot be used globally without problems, how can I restrict it only to `siunitx` `\num{}` command? I tried defining a new command with `\pdfminusON ... \pdfminusOFF` but it doesn't compile.

Comment: @homocomputeris I don't know enough about `siunitx` to be able to fix that one, but I will keep thinking.  You could always accept this answer and then ask that as a new question, citing this one.